# Amazon S3 viewing files

Tags: amazon-s3

Hi I have recently set up an amazon s3 account for a personal project.
I have successfully uploaded some image(jpg) files and  have set the ACL for the bucket to public however when trying to view a file via the browser, the following xml is returned instead of the jpg.

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>77293A7937279B15</RequestId>
−
<HostId>
cQ3FXKg7ZU4z80QqUGMBheG0FRrFJP4HQx1pCy6UTFDk4pbjR8oYuCa1BmS6jnpe
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Am I missing something here? Do I need to set up a distribution, or should I be able to access the files regardless?
Any hints much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the ACP of the resource (object) to anonymous ("public"), as well.

Note that this is not a programming question. If you need S3 support, check out the [Amazon S3 forum](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/forum.jspa?forumID=24).

Comment: Bingo, thanks for the heads up I will check out the furom.